# Not receiving the broadcast while running the LocationPollerDemo

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I've searched through a number of the questions and answers in regards to the [LocPoller](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) from Commonsware and haven't found the answer to my problem.  I have tried using the demo of the latest from github and I'm having issues.  First I must admit that I modified the PERIOD in the demo so the alarm fires every 15 seconds.  I realize this will be a large drain on the batter and it's just for testing.  I would expect that the [LocationReceiver's](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/locpoll/demo/LocationReceiver.java) onReceive() would be called ever 15 seconds but that isn't happening.

Debugging things I see that the alarm is triggering and everything seems good in that it's getting to the PollerThread and calling sendBroadcast.  So I assume I have something setup wrong, but I'm not sure what.  Other than changing the PERIOD in the demo everything else is as is.  I've tried running this on a device and emulator (Level 8).  Any help in debugging this would be appreciated.

In the end the functionality I'm looking for is to have the ability to keep track of a phones location so at any point my app can get the current location.  I saw this in my research and though it fit the bill perfect.  If someone has a better idea of different approach I'd love to hear it.

Thanks,
Rindress

Answer (score 1):

> In the end the functionality I'm looking for is to have the ability to keep track of a phones location so at any point my app can get the current location. I saw this in my research and though it fit the bill perfect.

No, it is not.

> If someone has a better idea of different approach I'd love to hear it.

Step #1: Call `requestLocationUpdates()` when you want to start receiving location updates in your app

Step #2: Use the location fixes delivered to your `LocationListener`, or call `getLastKnownLocation()`, as needed

Step #3: Call `removeUpdates()` when you no longer want to receive location updates in your app

Comment: "which it could be running in the background for a very long time, possibly always" -- your users may not like this very much. "Also this didn't answer my original question which was just about the LocationPollerDemo?" -- 15 seconds is an inappropriate period for `LocationPoller`. The complete and entire point behind `LocationPoller` is to give you *occasional* location updates *when your app is not running*. Hence, `LocationPoller` is not suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Got it thanks.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer, and clarify the response.  I totally understand that users will not like this approach, however; I have not found another approach that would still give good location information and be less of a battery drain.

Thanks again for the quick responses.